# How to solve $x^x=a$ and related equations?

Tags: exponential-function, tetration, transcendental-equations

How can I solve the equation for $x$ when $x^x=2$ or any other constant? And is solving $x^{x^x}=a$ or $x^{x^{x^x}}=a$ or equations such as these even possible? What are these equations even called?

And what about the following?
$$x^{(x-1)^{(x-2)^{\dots^{3^{2^{1}}}}}}=k$$ 
or
$$a\;x@n+b\;x@(n-1)+c\;x@(n-2)+\cdots=0$$ 
where "$@$" is an operator I made to indicate the number of exponents, as $x@3:=x^{x^x}$.

I have already tried taking logarithms, using taylor series, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of the questions listed above, except for the simplest case of $x^x=a$. OP seems to be interested in the algebraic properties of ["tetration"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) in general. (That said, there may be duplicate questions about tetration. After all, there's a `tetration` tag.)

Comment: For the most basic case of $x^x=a$, you can use the Lambert-W function. You will find that $x=e^{W(\ln a)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first make the substitution $x = e^t$.
$$a = \left(e^t\right)^{e^t}$$
$$a = e^{te^t}$$
$$\ln a = te^t$$
This is now of the form $y = xe^x$. The inverse of this equation is known as the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). This means that
$$t = W(\ln a)$$
$$x = e^{W(\ln a)}$$
After this point, you must evaluate on a case by case basis. You could either look up specific values of Lambert W or you could find the values using either [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or [Halley's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method).